# How to ignore to serialization of a dropdown select element in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a form I need to ignore `serialization` of a select/option drop-down element as I need to hook a separate event to it. As the whole form is saved in the beginning, how to ignore certain elements like the select/option drop-down?

I tried:
`$('#form').not('#signup,#idGarage').data('serialize',$('#form').serialize());`
It has no effect tho.

**Here is the code:**

```
<form>
.
.
.
<div class="input">

   <label for="signup">Name</label>
   <select id="signup" class="signup" name="signupId" data-placeholder="Select">
        <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
        <option value="Cars">Bikes</option>
        <option value="Cars">Trucks</option>
   </select>

   <input type="hidden" name="signupId" id="idGarage" value="{$idGarage.id}">

   <a href="" title="" class="send-garage-invite">Send</a>
</div>
.
.
.
</form>
```

---

```
$('#form').data('serialize',$('#form').serialize()); // On load save form current state

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){
   if($('#form').serialize()!=$('#form').data('serialize')){
      return true;
   } 
   else  e=null; // i.e; if form state change show warning box, else don't show it.
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to serialize the whole form. In selector choose the elements you want to serialize.

```
$('form').data('serialize', $('form input:not([type="hidden"])').serialize());
```

Comment: How to do this on select element?

Comment: Do you want to ignore select or include it?

Comment: I need to ignore it.

Comment: You can change this `$('form input:not([type="hidden"])')` to any selector you want. by not including any element it will ignore it. For example if you want to choose all select except a certain one you can use `$('form select:not([class="any"])');` or you can add multiple elements  `$('input[type='radio'], input[type='text'])')`

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the guidance. Now when I add this as you said, with class signup as so:  ```$('form select:not([class=".signup-space"])').data('serialize', $('form select:not([class="signup-space"])').serialize()); ```

Even when there are no changes to any of the form fields it has an aler asking if the user wants to leve as they can lose the data.